# Removing duplicates tuples in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates, tuples

I can't figure out how to remove all the duplicates from a list of tuples
e.g [(1,2),(2,1),(5,2),(5,6)]

Here the duplicate would be (2,1) (irrelevant of order). I only want to remove one of the duplicates, how would I do this?

```
symEq :: Eq a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Bool
symEq (x,y) (u,v) = (x == u && y == v) || (x == v && y == u)

removeDuplTuples :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
removeDuplTuples = nubBy symEq
```

Here is some code I read but I don't think it is entirely relevant

Comment: In this case I want (2,1) to be a duplicate

Comment: have you tried running that code?

Comment: Yes it returns an error saying nubBy is an undefined variable

Comment: ``nubBy`` is in the Data.List package, you have to import it to use it.

Comment: @ThreeFx why quickly?

Comment: @Arnon I was distracted and typed garbage XD It is a [commonly known  phenomenon](https://xkcd.com/604/).

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted is entirely relevant, it is exactly what you want...

Lets step through it:

`symEq` takes two tuples and checks whether the first and last elements are equal OR if the elements across from each other are equal.

`nubBy` is just `nub` using a custom function instead of `(==)`.

`nubBy` is in the `Data.List` package, just do `import Data.List` at the beginning of the file to be able to use it.

Comment: I've tried doing that but it there is an error with the import for some reason

Comment: @Sprout Try doing ``import Data.List (nubBy)``